# How can i get in Nuxt/Vue Store from js async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, fingerprint

I using fingerprintjs module in my Nuxt project and I am a newbie for frontend framework.

I can get User fingerprint code in console but I can't use the VuexStore instance.

```js
if (process.browser) {
  const fpPromise = FingerprintJS.load();
  (async () => {
      // Get the visitor identifier when you need it.
      const fp = await fpPromise
      const result = await fp.get()

      // This is the visitor identifier:
      const visitorId = result.visitorId
      console.log(visitorId)
  })()
}
```

How can I use vuexStore in an instance of visitorId?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you with this code?

If it's inside a Nuxt plugin (`/plugins/my-plugin.js` for example), then you could use this

```js
export default ({ store }) => {
  // your code
}
```

As shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/context-helpers

---

If you're in usual `script` section in a `.vue` file, then this should be enough

```js
if (this.$store.state.auth.loggedIn) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: No member login required. I want to get fingerprint without membership. So i using codes in store/index.js (Store)

Comment: The "login" was just part of the example. If you are already in the store, simply write your thing in it. What are you trying to achieve with Vuex here?

Comment: I want to be able to use it over and over again or assign it to a state. for example: I want to add the visitor id while adding upvote to the database. but i get promise as response. When I try to use it in nuxtServerInit it doesn't work.

Comment: @Orates I did not get what you want here.